# Node.js (telegraf) - Ошибка в session при создании wizard.scene

Tags: node.js, telegraf

**Версии**, которые я пробовал:

1. telegraf: 4.12.0 & node: 18.18.2
2. telegraf: 4.14.0 & node: 21.0.0

Фрагмент модуля, который я использую:

```js
const { Composer, Scenes, session } = require('telegraf');
const composer = new Composer()

const stepOne = composer.hears('text', async (ctx) => {
  await ctx.reply('Пожалуйста, введите ваш номер телефона')
  const fullName = ctx.message.text;
  if (validateFullName(fullName)) {
    ctx.wizard.state.data = {
      fullName: fullName
    };
    return ctx.wizard.next();
  } else {
  return ctx.reply ('Попробуйте еще раз, пжлст')
}
}); 


const stepTwo = composer.hears('text', async (ctx) => {
  await ctx.reply('Спасибо! Ваша заявки принята');
  const phoneNumber = ctx.message.text;
  if (validatePhoneNumber(phoneNumber)) {
    ctx.wizard.state.data = {
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber
    };

    // отправляем данные 
    const adminChatId = '...'; 
    const userData = ctx.wizard.state.data;
    ctx.telegram.sendMessage(adminChatId, `Получена новая заявка:\nФИО: ${userData.fullName}\nНомер телефона: ${userData.phoneNumber}`);

    return ctx.scene.leave();
  } else {
  console.log('error: unvalidate phone');
  return ctx.reply ('Кажется, это не номер телефона. Повторите, пжлст')
  }
});

const contactWizardScene = new Scenes.WizardScene('contactFormWizard', stepOne, stepTwo)

const stage = new Scenes.Stage([contactWizardScene])
stage.register(contactWizardScene)

module.exports = {
  contactWizardScene,
  stage
}

composer.use(session())
composer.use(stage.middleware())

composer.command('contactForm', (ctx) => { 
  ctx.reply('Как я могу к вам обращаться? (Ф.И.О.)');
  ctx.scene.enter('contactFormWizard')
});


module.exports = composer
```

**Ошибка**:

```
C:\Users\...\node_modules\telegraf\lib\session.js:86
        Object.defineProperty(ctx, prop, {
               ^

TypeError: Cannot redefine property: session
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\...\node_modules\telegraf\lib\session.js:86:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async execute (C:\Users\...\node_modules\telegraf\lib\composer.js:501:17)
    at async C:\Users\...\node_modules\telegraf\lib\composer.js:502:21      
    at async execute (C:\Users\...\node_modules\telegraf\lib\composer.js:501:17)
    at async C:\Users\...\node_modules\telegraf\lib\composer.js:502:21      

Node.js v21.0.0
```

**Комментарий:**

Прошу прощения, если я коряво/плохо/неправильно оформил обращение. Это мой первый вопрос на подобных форумах. Буду благодарен за конструктивную критику.

Я не понимаю. Что не так? Я пробовал исключить composer из кода, разные версии и совместимости. Ничего из этого мне не помогло. Кажется, ошибка какая-то детская и легко решаемая. Видимо, моего опыта недостаточно чтобы ее понять. Прошу, памагите...

Comment: покажите немного больше трейса ошибки

Comment: @nörbörnën, внес изменения. Спасибо